# Correct way to repaint entire screen?

Tags: c++, c, ncurses, curses

I don't understand what function(s) to use to repaint the screen when the user presses Ctrl-L or Ctrl-R. What's the difference between using `clearok()`, `redrawwin()`, or `wrefresh()` with `curscr` as argument? From the OpenBSD man pages:

> If clearok is called with TRUE as argument, the next call to wrefresh with this window will clear the screen completely and redraw the entire screen from scratch.  This is useful when the contents of the screen are uncertain, or in some cases for a more pleasing visual effect.  If the win argument to clearok is the global variable curscr, the next call to wrefresh with any window causes the screen to be cleared and repainted from scratch.

...

> If the win argument to wrefresh is the global variable curscr, the screen is immediately cleared and repainted from scratch.

...

> The wredrawln routine indicates to curses that some screen lines are corrupted and should be thrown away before anything is written over them.  It touches the indicated lines (marking them changed).  The routine redrawwin() touches the entire window.

Comment: I don't understand. Ctrl+L and Ctrl+R? Where did you get those key combinations from? What are you trying to do?

Comment: And the difference between the techniques is as described in the quotes. Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ctrl-L is a very common "repaint the screen" command, recognized by curses-based programs like `more`, `less`, `vi`, `dialog`, `screen` (with Ctrl-A prefix), `lynx`, `info`, ... pretty much anything that interacts with the user using the whole screen. Ctrl-R may be a less common substitute. The reason for wanting to associate Ctrl-L and/or Ctrl-R with this function in a new program isn't unclear at all, it's simply for consistency with what users have learned from all those other programs.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: Then add that detail to the question please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ["OpenBSD manpages"](http://man.openbsd.org/curses.3) are [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html).  The key-bindings are irrelevant.
You've asked about three features:

1. [clearok()](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_outopts.3x.html#h3-clearok),
2. [redrawwin()](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html#h3-wredrawln_redrawwin), or
3. [wrefresh()](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html#h3-wnoutrefresh_doupdate) with curscr as argument?

But those are different:

- with `clearok()`, you are not telling curses that you've lost track of what's on the screen, but saying that it's preferable to clear it (and curses will do that), but
- `redrawwin()` isn't repainting the whole screen, but a **window**.  Your application might do this if it is imitating the panel library, making some windows overlap and wanting to "raise" an obscured window above the others.  Finally,
- refreshing `curscr` explicitly is telling curses to bypass the normal sequence of printing onto a window, or onto `stdscr`, then applying changes from `stdscr` onto **`newscr`**, and applying differences between **`newscr`** and **`curscr`** **to** **`curscr`**.  As far as curses is concerned, **`curscr`** has whatever is put onto the physical screen.  So when you modify **`curscr`**, curses updates the physical screen as soon as it is asked to refresh.

For what it's worth, the **`curscr`** feature predates ncurses, though I'd have to point to [source-code](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/td_lib-snapshots/blob/master/src/curses/wrepaint.c) to show that.  It's mentioned in this [changelog entry from 1995](http://invisible-island.net/ded/td_lib/CHANGES.html#t19950703) though:

> **`src/curses/resizwin.c`**:
>           refresh curscr to force screen update in ncurses

Answer (score 0):

Usually what happend when Ctrl+L or Ctrl+R are pressed is matter of your shell or the program in use, in this case the program will send a sequence of characters your terminal will interprate when (the terminal) will clear your screen.

How to get this sequence :

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <term.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

void init_term(void)
{
  static struct termios term_new;

  setupterm(NULL, 1, NULL);
  ioctl(0, TCGETS, &term_new);
}


int             main(void)
{
  // init the ncurses
  init_term();
  // get the sequence for "clear" command then print it 
  printf("%s", tigetstr("clear"));
  // and flush the buffer
  fflush(stdout);
  return (0);
}
```